# extract the columns that can be divided by 5 in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 200 columns, I want to extract column 5, 10, 15, 20...195, 200 for a new df. But I don't want to type all of them. Is there any method to make it easier?

```
df1 <- df[,c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,...,200)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `seq` to create the index

```
df1 <- df[, seq(5, 200, by = 5)]
```

Comment: Great, what if I also want to keep column 1-4?

Comment: df1 <- df[,c(1:4,seq(5, 200, by = 5))] is not working.

Comment: @JinyongHuang that should work.  What is the error you. are getting

Comment: @JinyongHuang If I do `c(1:4,seq(5, 200, by = 5))#
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95
[24] 100 105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 165 170 175 180 185 190 195 200`

Comment: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , c(1:4, seq(5, 200, by = 5))) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: I got it. I have only 175 columns on my real data set.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @JinyongHuang then you can change the `seq(5, 175, by = 5)`

Comment: @JinyongHuang the reason I used 200 is from your post which states 200 columns